# ps2pdf does not honour Pagesize directive

Tags: pdf, postscript

Postscript 3.0 file requires A3 size:

```
~/home_shared/project/auto/2020$ head -1 electr.ps
%!PS-Adobe-3.0

~/home_shared/project/auto/2020$ grep -i bound electr.ps
%%PageBoundingBox: 0 0 842 1191 % A3 papierformaat
```

Still the resulting pdf is for "letter" paper size which is the last thing I want, being in Europe.

```
~/home_shared/project/auto/2020$ ps2pdf -sPapersize=A3 electr.ps
~/home_shared/project/auto/2020$ pdfinfo electr.pdf
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.26
CreationDate:   Tue Mar 31 11:57:12 2020 GMT
ModDate:        Tue Mar 31 11:57:12 2020 GMT
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          2
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
Page rot:       0
File size:      2848 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

Is this a bug, or is there something I missed or misunderstood?
This is on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, religiously patched to most recent state.

Comment: If it uses "letter" presently, that might well come from the default "locale" setting; still no reason the Papersize option should not override the default.

Comment: As I suspected, I found that ps2pdf does honour the environment variable $PAPERSIZE. So I can make it work with export PAPERSIZE=A3; ps2pdf $MYFILE but I consider that a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The lines you've highlihgted are comments (PostScript comments begin with '%'). In general a conforiming PostScritp itnerpreter will ignore comment lines altogether.

So its not that ps2pdf is failing to 'honour the PageSize directive' the problem is much more likely to be that the input file does not contain a setpagedevice request to alter the media size.

In that case you will get the default media size whcih for Ghostscript is usually either Letter or A4 depending on how the binary was built, and the the presence or absence of some extra utilities like libpaper (and whether the binary was built to use these).